# Tikz - operation between integers results in decimal

Tags: pgfmath

The first example prints integers 0 to 3 as expected but the second changes all output to decimal despite the calculation only involving integers. How can I avoid this behavior?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Example}
\author{}
\date{October 5th, 2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%First
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
\draw (\i,0) node {$\pgfmathprint{\i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

%Second
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
\draw (\i,0) node {$\pgfmathprint{\i+1}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!! You can use `\pgfmathprint{int(\i+1)}`.

Comment: PGFmath has its own [number printing module](https://tikz.dev/math-numberprinting): `\pgfset{number format/int detect}\pgfmathparse{\i+1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,siunitx}

\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 0} % fix # of decimal places

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{\i+1}
    \draw (\i,0) node  {\num{\j}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

**Edit**
If you need one or more decimal place modify one line of code:

```
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 1} % fix # of decimal places
```